# How to reduce a data with the longest string under pandas framework?

Tags: python, pandas

How to reduce a data with the longest string under pandas framework?
I tried the following code, but get `ValueError: invalid number of arguments`.

```
def f1(s):
    return max(s, key=len)

data.groupby('id').agg({'name':(lambda s: f1(s)) })
```

Ex. Input

```
id name
GB "United Kingdom"
GB England
US "United States"
US America
```

Output:

```
id name
GB "United Kingdom"
US "United States"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code should work. BTW, you don't need to wrap `f1` inside another `lambda`. Just pass `f1`. (They have exactly same parameter signature)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> def f1(s):
...     return max(s, key=len)
...
>>> data = pd.DataFrame([
...     {'id': 'GB', 'name': '"United Kingdom"'},
...     {'id': 'GB', 'name': 'England'},
...     {'id': 'US', 'name': '"United States"'},
...     {'id': 'US', 'name': 'America'},
...
... ])
>>> data.groupby('id').agg({'name': f1})
                name
id
GB  "United Kingdom"
US   "United States"
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by @falsetru.

Alternatively with lambda function:

```
data.groupby('id').agg({'name': lambda s: max(s, key=len)})
```